# Add border to a row or table cell in GDocs using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a several tables in GDoc and I want to add border to the newly inserted row of the last table in GDoc.
The below code will not add a border to the newly created row.

```
function addBordertoLastTable() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();

    var tables = body.getTables();

    table = tables[tables.length - 1];
    var tr = table.appendTableRow();

    var cellStyle = (table.getRow(0).getAttributes())
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#343434';
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '8';
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = '#c0c0c0';
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#00ff00';
    cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = '8';

    tr.setAttributes(cellStyle);
    tr.appendTableCell('My Text').setAttributes(cellStyle);
    tr.appendTableCell('My Text').setAttributes(cellStyle);
    tr.appendTableCell('My Text').setAttributes(cellStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute

```
BORDER_COLOR    Enum    The border color, for table elements.
BORDER_WIDTH    Enum    The border width in points, for table elements.
```

BORDER_WIDTH and BORDER_COLOR are **table** properties, not cell properties.

You can add the following lines at the end of your function to make it work:

```
var tableStyle = {};
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_WIDTH] = 8; 
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BORDER_COLOR] = '#c0c0c0';
table.setAttributes(tableStyle);
```

If a newbie is reading this, it would also be good practice to delete the BORDER_COLOR and BORDER_WIDTH definitions from cellStyle, to make the code easier to read.